# how can we apply masked language modelling on the images using multimodal models?

Tags: transformers, multimodality

It might not be clear from the question what I want to say, but how can we apply masked language modelling with the text and image given using multimodal models like lxmert. For example, if there is some text given (This is a MASK) and we mask some word in it, and there is an image given (maybe of a cat), how can we apply MML to predict the word as cat? Are there any techniques to solve such problems? If anyone can help, it would be great.

Comment: Questions on Cross Validated are expected to be well-researched. Instead of asking someone to do your literature review, what have you found so far? If you don't know where to look, a great starting point on research in multimodal models is the ACL Anthology.

Comment: As I am not able to find a paper which did this kind of work, so, I am asking here. If anyone knows, can share their knowledge? I mean, I want to get scores of such models from the huggingface library api.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.